# Using opencv / Numpy to find white pixels in a color image using python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image I loaded using opencv, that I would like to find pixels that are white.

```
input_img = [[[255,255,255], [0,127,255]],
             [[255,255,255], [255,127,255]]]
```

should return

```
white = [[1, 0],
         [1, 0]]
```

Is there a way to do this without reshaping or without an expensive for loop?  Using something like numpy.where?

Comment: Are you looking for pure white or pixels that looks close to white? Because of noise in images, some of the pixels will not be exactly, (255, 255, 255). Perhaps post a sample test image if that is convenient.

Comment: These are white pixels - the image I receive already has noise removed (or at least I can assume that it has).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
(input_img == 255).all(axis=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
input_img = [[[255,255,255], [0,127,255]],
         [[255,255,255], [255,127,255]]]
white = np.array(np.sum(input_img, axis=-1) == 765, dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: maybe i got it wrong, but how come this returns this `(array([0, 1]), array([0, 0]))`